# Translate Pinch touch gesture to scroll mouse wheel

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, touch, gestures

I don't know if it's the right Community, if it's not, please point me to where I should ask.

I need an application that can translate a pinch gesture I make on my touch screen to a mouse wheel scroll. This because I have a WPF control (whose code I cannot access) that is not browseable using touch, and therefore I need something that listens to gesture events and translates them into other events... I'm using Windows 8.1.

Thank you for any help.